# Data Updating of JSON doesn't work (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, json, database

So I have a Table in a Database that looks like this:

### Category

idCategory | data

the "idCategory" column is AUTO_INCREMENT and the data field is a JSON. 
I have data stored in the table looking like this:

```
1, {"CategoryNames": {"DE": "Wirtschaft", "EN": "Economy"}}
2, {"CategoryNames": {"DE": "Geschichte", "EN": "History"}}
```

The Idea is, to Store the name for a Category in different Languages. I preferably need the "CategoryNames" tag, so I can add other Properties like "Difficulty" or so, later without affecting the languages.

What I want to do, is to add other Languages under the Tag "CategoryNames" without deleting or Replacing the existing ones.

So it would look somthething like this

```
2, {"CategoryNames": {"DE": "Geschichte", "EN": "History", "FR" : "Histoire"}}
```

I have tried it with `JSON_INSERT` with something like this:

```
UPDATE phpframework.category SET data = JSON_INSERT(data, "$.CategoryNames", JSON_OBJECT('FR', 'Histoire')) WHERE idCategory = 2;
```

But nothing happens, the Column remains the same. With `JSON_SET` it just replaces my existing languages. I also tried `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` But then it looks like this:

```
{"CategoryNames": [{"DE": "Geschichte", "EN": "History"}, {"EN": "Math"}]}
```

Does anyone know the right MYSQL command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to insert a whole object, you want to set a property in an existing object.

```
UPDATE phpframework.category 
SET data = JSON_INSERT(data, "$.CategoryNames.FR", 'Histoire') 
WHERE idCategory = 2;
```

You could also use `JSON_SET` instead of `JSON_INSERT` if you want it to replace a property that already exists.

Comment: Wow Thanks! Is there also the possiblity, to add multiple languages and their CategoryNames at once? Or do I have to make a query for each of the Languages I want to add for a Category?

Comment: `JSON_INSERT` allows multiple insertions: `JSON_INSERT(data, '$.CategoryNames.FR', 'Histoire', '$.CategoryNames.EN', 'History')`

Comment: The documentation even has examples that insert multiple items.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!